# Activity indicator for 5seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uiactivityindicatorview

All

I am trying to run `UIActivityIndicator` for a 5 seconds on `viewdidappear` method .But how do i give a time limit for activity indicator(5 seconds)  ?

This is the code for `UIActivityIndicator`

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;

    [activityView startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With one line and no additional dependencies & conditions:

```
[activityView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: removefrom superview is a system method ryt?

Comment: @user2439088 its working perfectly.. is it not working for you ?

Comment: `removeFromSuperview` is an `UIView` function, so it should work for any `UIView` subclass (`UIActivityIndicatorView` included). @user2439088, where do you put this code?

Answer (score 4):

Set activity view to hide automatically when stopped

```
activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

And hide it after 5s like this:

```
[activityView performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

This will allow you to start animation again by just calling `startAnimating` if you need so in the future and keep pointer to the `UIActivityIndicatorView`

If you just need to show activity indicator once and will not use it anymore, *Alexanders* answer will suit best to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer for 5 sec.
In the call back method of timer stop the animation

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        activityView.center=self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:activityView];
        [activityView startAnimating];
        activityView.tag=1111;
        [activityView release];
}   


    [activityView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    -(void)removeFromSuperview
    {
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=(UIActivityIndicatorView*)[self.viewviewWithTag:1111];
            [activityView stopAnimating];
[activityView removeFromSuperview];
        }
```